# Prove $S=[0,1)^\mathbb{N}$ is a Borel subset of $[0,\,1]^\mathbb{N}$.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $M=[0,\,1]^\mathbb{N}$ be the space of all sequences $\left(x_n\right)_{1}^\infty$ with $x_n\in \left[0,\,1\right]$.
Let $\rho$ be a metric defined by
$$
\rho(x, y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|x_{n}-y_{n}\right| / 2^{n}.
$$
It is easy to check that $M$ is a complete separable metric space.

Let $S=[0,\,1)^\mathbb{N}$.
Considering $\left(x_n\right)\in S$ with $x_n=1-1/n$, we know that $S$ is not open.
So I don't know how to prove $S$ is a Borel subset.

Comment: Is $T_n$ open where $T_n=M$ but with $x_n \not=1$?  Can you then take $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty T_n$?

Comment: Your way to state that $S$ is not open is wrong. Your example is a sequence in $S$ that does not converge, but $S$ is a space of sequences so you should make a sequence of sequences that does not converge to a sequence. Consider $(x^{(k)}_n)$ where $x^{(k)} = (x^k_1, x^k_2, ...)$. Then $x^{(k)} \rightarrow x$ but $x \not \in S$ is a counter example, where $x$ is a sequence.

Comment: @AukeSchaap I meant $(x_n)$ is an element of $S$ and $x_n=1-1/n$ is the $n$th component of $(x_n)$.

Comment: @Henry Good idea, I elaborated on it in an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by Henry choose
$$T_n=\{x\in M:x_n\neq 1\},n\in \mathbb{N}.$$
For fixed $n$ and $x\in T_n$, choosing $0<\varepsilon<\frac{1-|x_n|}{2^n}$ we have, for  $y\in B_{\varepsilon}(x)$, that $$\rho(x,y)=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{|x_j-y_j|}{2^j}<\varepsilon;$$
this implies
$$|y_n|-|x_n|\leq|y_n-x_n|<\varepsilon 2^n<1-|x_n|$$ and thus $|y_n|<1$ which shows $y\in T_n$ and thus $B_{\varepsilon}(x)\subset T_n$.
This proves $T_n$ is open and you can finish as suggested by Henry:
$$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}T_n=S$$
which shows $S$ is a Borel set in $M$

Comment: The argument as written makes no sense. There is no $\varepsilon>0$ that satisfies $\varepsilon<(1-|x_n|)/2^n$ for all $n$.

Comment: I ment for given $n$ choose $\varepsilon$ so that ...to show each $T_n$ is open

Comment: Fair enough. I edited  your answer to try to make it more clear, but mostly to be able to remove my downvote. Please feel free to rollback if you want.

Comment: @MartinArgerami Thank You very much indeed!